# GA4 Purchase (and variables) visible as event but no e-commerce / revenue

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

The datalayer is pushing all required variables (checked with debug and datalayer checker), the tag and trigger are firing via GTM. The variables (name client, ID, price, tax, etc) are also visible in a ‘purchase’ event under the tab ‘Events’ in GA4 but the revenue is not registering, stays at 0 and none of the variables are actually integrated in the ‘Ecommerce’ section of GA4.

What am I missing? Below the code on the check-out page, XXX being variables that work but are deleted. Thanks in advance lovely folks.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || \\\[\\\]; 
    dataLayer.push({ 
                      'event': 'purchase', 
                      'transactionId': 'XXX', 
                      'transactionAffiliation': 'XXX', 
                      'transactionTotal': '106.56', 
                      'transactionTax': '0.00', 
                      'transactionShipping': '0.00', 
                      'sku': 'XXX', 
                      'name': 'XXX', 
                      'category': 'XXX', 
                      'currency': 'EUR', 
                      'price': '106.56', 
                      'quantity': '1', 
                      'transactionProducts': 'XXX', 
    }); 
    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', { 
                       'id': 'XXX', // Transaction ID. Required 
                       'affiliation': 'XXX', // Affiliation or store name 
                       'revenue': '106.56', // Grand Total 
                       'shipping': '0.00', // Shipping 
                       'tax': '0.00' // Tax 
    }); 
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 
                       'id': 'XXX', // Transaction ID. Required 
                       'name': 'XXX', // Product name. Required 
                       'sku': 'XXX', // SKU/code 
                       'category': 'XXX', // Category or variation 
                       'price': '106.56', // Unit price        
                       'quantity': '1' // Quantity 
    }); 
    ga('ecommerce:send'); 
    fbq("track", "Purchase", {value: "106.56", currency: "EUR"});
</script>
```

Tried to change triggers/tags etc. however we are getting the same error.